# 404 not found when show data by slug in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to show a post using slug but always get 404 not found.

Controller

```
    public function show($slug)
{
    $post = Post::findorFail($slug);
    $tags = Tag::all();

    return view('page.detail', compact('post', 'tags'));
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('/post/{slug}', 'PageController@show');
```

View

```
@foreach($post as $item)
<a href="/post/{{$item->slug}}" class="btn-custom">Read More <span
 class="ion-ios-arrow-forward">
@endforeach
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findOrFail()` checks against primary key of your `Post.php` model, which is typically `id`, so your query is currently:

> `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = 'contents-of-slug'`

Your code should work if you do the following:

```
$post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
```

See the documentation; it shows this exact example:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions